# What I am - an animal (may be)?

Tags: riddle, word

What I am

> People call me an animal
>
> Since I possess a tail
>
> but it's in the opposite direction.
>
> I can't travel beyond some point
>
> Since I am bound by my tail.
>
> Sometimes I don't have a tail
>
> But still I can not travel that far.
>
> Go to the right and the world is easy for you.
>
> Go to the left and change your mode.
>
> You touch me often, but I won't bite you.
>
> So what am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **A computer mouse**
>
> A mouse is an animal
> The 'tail' comes out of the top, rather than the bottom
> Some are wireless, so have no tail, but are still bound by the receiver's range
> Going right takes you away from the keyboard, which is easy to do
> I'm not sure about the left clue
> You have your hand on it a lot without being bitten

Comment: Yep correct...:)

Comment: What's the deal with the right and left? Me too can't figure out why going left changes mood

Comment: Maybe the right / left clues are about using the mouse as right-handed or left-handed. As being right-handed is more common, that would make the world an easier place. Could "mood" refer to it's origins in the word "mode"?

Comment: I think (since right is away from the keyboard) it's because you can use a keyboard for emoticons/more general status updates?

Comment: Not for those lefthanded...for me, right is _towards_ the keyboard. And I don't even use a reversed mouse as many lefthanded do, so I guess I'm bound not to understand this part :)

Comment: yes my mistake i wanted to write it as Mode...for left hand users...i would edit it..:)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are

> a keyboard

People call me an animal

> that's the one I miss, maybe a reference to the keyboard cat?

Since I possess a tail

> that's the wire

but it's in the opposite direction.

> when I'm using it, the "tail" is indeed in opposite direction

I can't travel beyond some point

> well, the wire must not be unplugged

Since I am bound by my tail.

> bound with the computer

Sometimes I don't have a tail

> wireless ones, maybe?

But still I can not travel that far.

> Wireless, if I go too far, I might lose the signal

Go to the right and world is easy for you.

> numpad in on the right, and make life easier, compared to using the other numbers

Go to the left and change your mode.

> capslock is on the left, and often used to convey anger, on forums

You touch me often, but I won't bite you.

> yes, I touch it very often (I wouldn't be able to answer, if not) .. and never been bitten

Comment: Good try....but some clue's seems forcefully adjusted..:)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer has been posted, but this was my initial guess.

I think you are:

> A **ring buffer** or **FIFO (first-in, first-out) queue**
>  [image: ring buffer]

People call me an animal

Since I possess a tail

but its in opposite direction.

> Not sure about the animal part. The tail can end up in front of the head once the head wraps around after having reached the end of the buffer.

I cant travel beyond some point

Since i am bound by my tail.

> A ring buffer is considered full when head = tail-1 (mod N). At this point, the head can no longer advance and so you can no longer push data to the ring buffer.

Sometimes I don't have a tail

But still I can not travel that far.

> The tail points to stale data once it has caught up to the head, i.e. head = tail. Even starting with no tail, the head can only advance by N, where N is the (finite) size of the ring buffer.

Go to right and world is easy for you.

Go to left and change your mode.

> A ring buffer always travels to the right, towards increasing memory, until wrap-around occurs after a total of N steps.

You touch me often, but I won't bite you.

> A ring buffer can be used many times per second, allowing information to transfer at rates of 100s of MB per second.